# Is it useful to divide a vector xml background into m*n childview small background? (Android)

Tags: android, canvas, view, ondraw

I am new to android, some people says that don't use a large size png to be a background of some rpg game. They prefer to use small pixie drawable to make up a rpg game in 15-20 years ago.

However, svg path seems to be different.
I want to ask if I have a 1080(W)*2133(H) mobile phone,
If I have some paths to be drawn on canvas, like a clock with some details and text inside.
Is there any advantage to use `clipRect` with Rect size = w/m * h/n,
with the same paths didn't simplified for each smaller view.

e.g.
I want to draw a background like this

[A B]

[C D]

I divide the view into 4 smaller views [A] [B] [C] [D] and use `clipRect` to draw.
However, some paths, say path1, path2 ,path3 ,path4 ,path5 ,path6 will pass through more than 1 view of views A,B,C,D for each path. so I need to use the command `drawPath` for all these paths in each view.

Question 1:
I think although I divide the large view into these 4 smaller views,
I make the work harder and do m*n-1 more extra works=.=

Question 2:
Is it useful (e.g. save memory or CPU?) if I divide the view into 10 x 10 smaller views while I have a view of size [w/30,h/30] with animation moving over these views?